# Terminated App due to memory pressure While creating Video ios

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, avassetwriter

I am create the video using the Array of images . If I select more than 40 images from gallery it gives the **Error:Terminated App Due to memory pressure** I am use CVPixelBufferRef to create the Video.

- I write to create the video

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<[_slideshowArray count]; i++) {
  UIImage *img=[_slideshowArray objectAtIndex:i];
  buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] size:imageSize];
  BOOL append_ok = NO;
  int j = 0;
  while (!append_ok && j < 9999) {
      if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
          //  NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%lu)",frameCount,(unsigned long)[imageArray count]);

          CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
          append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
          if(!append_ok){
              NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
              if(error!=nil) {
                  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
              }
          }
      }
      else {
          printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];
      }
      j++;
  }
  if (!append_ok) {
      printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
  }
  frameCount++;
  }
  [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
  [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:tm];
  [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
  NSLog(@"Write Ended");
  }];
  ```

  In this code _slideShowArray is my array that is the Array of UIImage.
  I put the screenshot of the instruments below.

When I create the video At that time memory will increase otherwise it is 9 or 10 MB.

**Note :** I am use ARC.

[image]

After the creating the video it does not release the memory.

I found the memory leaks in this project please help me..

[image: Memory Leak Image]

Comment: Rather than pre-load all of the images into an array, why not just load each image as you need it.  This will vastly reduce your memory requirement

Comment: I load only images that the user select from gallery

Comment: How is the array created?

Comment: The array contains image that only selected by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You do not release your buffer in your code.
Now you insert the below code.

```
CVPixelBufferPoolRef bufferPool = adaptor.pixelBufferPool;
            NSParameterAssert(bufferPool != NULL);
            CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
```

This code insert under the

```
        append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
```

I hope this will help you for release the memory